# Excel VBA to copy matching criteria cell and paste in a specific cell based on criteria in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to search for a specific text in a cell and copy it into a newly created list. I need to compare these values and have never used VBA. Below is an example of the criteria to search and copy the values.

[Oldparam sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqy9W.png)
[Newparam sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tpFO.png)

In the Newparam sheet, Column L needs to be filled with the matched text in OldParam sheet Column L based on the following example;

For when name is 20M408 and 20M408_1, in NewParam if Column F = st1CLOSE, copy the text from OldParam Column L only if Column G = OFFNRM.
If there is no match between the name and st1CLOSE with OFFNRM then NewParam Column L is filled with N/A.
Above is repeated for 20M409 and so on.

Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is not working with your code?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried below code however i'm unable to get the matching row number (for K = ) when match is found.

```html
Sub match()
 Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
 Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, L As Long, M As Long, NewName As String, NewValue As String
  
 Set s1 = Sheets("Report")
 Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet1")
 K = 1
 M = 1
 I = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 L = s2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

 For M = 2 To L
 
    If s2.Cells(M, "F").Value = "st1 CLOSE" Then
        NewName = s2.Cells(M, "B").Value
                  
        For K = 2 To I
        
            If s1.Cells(K, "K").Value = "OFFNRMPR" And s1.Cells(K, "A").Value = NewName Then
                s1.Cells(K, "L").Copy s2.Cells(M, "L").Value
                Exit For
            Else: s2.Cells(M, "L").Value = "N/A"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```